# Javascript: Getting the value of either of 2 or more undeclared variables

Tags: javascript

I have 2 variables `A` and `B`. One of them will be ***undeclared*** while the other will have a value. Rather than using if statements, is there a more elegant way to equate both of them to form only one variable? Like so:

```
if(A) {
    X = A
} else if(B) {
    X = B
}
```

Two if statements may be a relatively small size of code, but considering the fact that I may end up with more than 2 variables like that in future - certainly there's a better way to go about doing this?

Any help provided is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry I meant that one of them will be undeclared. If I do something like `X = A || B` I'll get a uncaught reference error

Comment: `X = A || B || C || …;`.

Comment: Why are you writing code that has undeclared variables in the first place? That's bad practice and you shouldn't be looking for ways to skirt around it.

Comment: Hi @JLRishe, thank you for your reply. I'm using the meteor account signup packages for facebook and email accounts. The username field get passed in as different variables after the user signs up, so I wanted a way to equate them into the same variable

Comment: @PohZiHow Can you give us a link to the documentation for that? Most people here probably don't know what the meteor account signup packages are.

Comment: @JLRishe the relevant article is here: https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html, though I don't think it explains the facebook bit in that much detail. I probably should figure a way to integrate the users schema so that theyre consistent with each other

Comment: @PohZiHow I skimmed that page but didn't see a part that really relates to this question. Please edit your question to clearly explain (in detail) what the situation is instead of using a vague example with dummy variable names. This may very well be an X->Y problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `||` operator:

```
X = A || B
```

In a nutshell `expr1 || expr2 || expr3 | ...` returns first expression that can be converted to true

Comment: Keep in mind that it uses Javascript's boolean logic, so if `A == 0` and `B == 'b'`, then `(A || B) == 'b'`.

Comment: Of course you're right. Thanks! But the same applies to example from question using  `if`

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want to find the first value that's not `undefined`, then you need to check whether the values are undefined. The value `0` is not `undefined`, but if you use `if (A)` when `A` is `0`, then the `if` statement's body will be skipped.

Here is a succinct way to pick the first non-undefined value:

```
var myValue = [A, B, C, D].find(function (val) {
    return typeof val !== 'undefined';
});
```

Or if you are writing for an environment that can use arrow functions:

```
var myValue = [A, B, C, D].find(val => typeof val !== 'undefined');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary operator:

`X = A ? A : B;`

Or for multiple variables:

`X = [A, B, C, D].find(x => x);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var X = (A) ? A : B;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
X = A && A || B && B;
```

or

```
X = A ? A : B;
```

Comment: The `&& A` and `&& B` are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Using ternary operator...

```
var A = null;
var B = 'This Has a Value';   
var OneVar = (A === null ? B : A);

console.log('OneVar: ' + OneVar);
```

**Console Result:** OneVar: This Has a Value